# Azure Function App Can't bind Table to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable'

Tags: azure, binding, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-webjobs

I'm working on this Azure Function App where I just need to use the method GET to retrieve all the users from Azure Storage Table. When I run my application I got the error:

Can't bind Table to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable'.

This is my code:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;

namespace FunctionEncrypt
{
    public class GetUser
    {
        [FunctionName("GetAll")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult>
            GetAll(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "users")] HttpRequest req,
            [Table("user", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] CloudTable cloudTable,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("Getting All users");

            TableQuery<UserTable>
            query = new TableQuery<UserTable>();
            var segment = await cloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, null);
            var data = segment.Select(UserExtensions.ToUser);

            return new OkObjectResult(data);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my Refences:
[image]

I have researched about this error, and every single place I looked for, says to replace the "using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;" for "using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table;", but even after I change the references, I still get the same error message. I also checked the versions and they are correct. When I changed for cosmos references, I change my package reference as well. I removed because I had issues before with multiple references.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `net6.0` `v4` please use only the following package:
`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Tables`

This means, you can uninstall `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage` if you are not using `Table` or `Queue` binding.

Finally, you have to clean up your code.
Delete using:
`using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;`

This means also, that `CloudTable` is no longer available.
You have to use the [TableClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableclient?view=azure-dotnet) or bind with [TableEntity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableentity?view=azure-dotnet)

Please find examples here:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Tables

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Data.Tables;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionEncrypt
{
  public class GetUser
  {
    [FunctionName("GetAll")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> GetAll(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "users")] HttpRequest req,
        [Table("user", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] TableClient client,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("Getting All users");
        var result = client.Query<Azure.Data.Tables.TableEntity>().ToList();
        return new OkObjectResult(result);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have also done this but my code cannot recognize the [Table("MyTable")] attribute, even though I'm stating "using Azure.Data.Tables;" and using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Tables with .NET 6 and Function v4.

Comment: @OliverNilsen I do not use any more Nuget packages. My usings:  
- `using Azure.Data.Tables;`    
- `using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;`   


My packages:
-  `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />`   
 
-  `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Tables" Version="1.0.0" />`  
-  `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.3" />`

Comment: When I have this one: Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions, I get the error that this cannot be used in Isolated process.

Comment: @OliverNilsen My code is not about isolated function. You have to use different packages

Comment: Does moving to TableClient from CloudTable mean refactoring all code using CloudTable in an existing function?

Comment: @CristianTeodorov yes, you have to refactor the code